# How to stop vim from inserting comment characters while pasting from the clipboard?

Tags: vim

When I paste lines, like the ones below, to Vim,

```
" OmniCppComplete
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1
```

Vim automagically adds the `"` comment character to all lines. How do I get rid of this and have it paste as it is?

```
What I'm getting after the paste in Vim:

 66     " OmniCppComplete
 67     " let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Two main options:

- Put directly from the register without ever entering insert mode, using  `"+p`

  - `"` means "use the following register";
  - `+` refers to the clipboard, and
  - `p` for put!

Should you be using the middle click selection paste in Linux, use `*` instead of `+` to refer to it.

- Before entering insert mode to paste, run `:set paste`. Turn it off once you leave insert mode with `:set nopaste`.

Comment: +1 I tried to make formatting a bit clearer (the literal quotations were _glueing_ together on my end)

Comment: Only the ``:set paste`` part worked for me (vim running on an Ubuntu box through a SSH connection from mac iTerm2 without X, hence probably no clipboard on the server side).

Comment: I don't understand `"+p` at all, but the `:set paste` method was perfect.

Comment: @Jake If you mean "+p doesn't work, it's probably because you're in a situation like Calimo, where the clipboard isn't actually available for Vim to see. If you mean you literally don't understand, well, while in normal mode, you literally type `"+p`.

Comment: I think I tried literally typing `"` `+` `p`, and I think you are saying to type `"` + `p` maybe? If that makes sense. So I probably just got confused. Will try again next time. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake No, I really do mean the literal three keystrokes. You should see `"+` in the status line after the first two, then the `p` will paste. If nothing happens, it's because vim can't see your OS clipboard.

Comment: K. Well you can see I am no expert on Vim. Likely, as you say, my clipboard wasn't visible. Thanks for the help. The other method worked great. I still need to learn more. Vim is a such a powerful tool.

Comment: Is it possible to use some settings in /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim and then use insert mode + paste from clipboard?

Comment: @Xdg I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. If you want to just paste in insert mode, and you're in a terminal, then you need to turn on paste mode. Vim can't really tell the difference between typing and pasting in terminals. (In gVim it probably can, so this is less of an issue there.) But you don't want paste mode to be on all the time, since in order to work it has to disable all those nice autoformatting things that you want when you're typing, so you really don't want to put it in defaults and have it on all the time.

Comment: I'm in terminal (PuTTY to headless server). I know that this inserting was working before some recent update (in Ubuntu). I was using insert mode and shift+insert to paste text from Windows clipboard.

Comment: @Xdg Sounds like you should ask a new question, then. I'm not really sure why it would've worked. It's possible to remap keys, I suppose, but I don't think it's ever worked by default as far as I know.

Answer (score 34):

In Vim go to the mode `:set paste`. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

It would work.

Don't paste by going to edit and paste. It won't work.

Comment: I was ssh'ing from mac to a remote ubuntu. It worked, but I had to enter `insert mode` in between the two commands

Comment: Shouldn't you press `i` for insert mode before Ctrl + Shift + V?

Answer (score 14):

Everybody so far is missing the point. Vim is automatically inserting the comment field when you start a new line (whether it is from a paste or from your typing).

You have formatoptions set with at least the r and maybe the o option. To see your settings, type

```
:set formatoptions?
```

To remove those options, type

```
:set formatoptions=
```

Paste will then work the way you expect.

Type

```
:help fo-table
```

to see what the letters in formatoptions each mean.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. formatoptions showed `formatoptions=croql` after removing ro using `:set formatoptions-=ro` I can past text form one putty session to vi edit mode. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on Vim in the UI, go to menu *Terminal* → *Reset and clear*. Then try to paste the code that you have.

It would get pasted as it is.